# When I find the kernel, should I use Tx=0 or Tx=1?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $S : F^{2,2} \rightarrow F^{2,2}$ be the linear transformation given by $S(A)= A+A^T$. 
Find a basis for Ker(S). What is nullity(S)? Is S one-to-one?

When I solve this problem I think I should find $\{A\mid S(A)=0\}$, which means Ker(S)={0}. I can only get the right answer when I solve S(A)=$[\begin{matrix} 1&0\\0&1 \end{matrix}]$. This is different with the definition of kernel, which makes me confused.

I also want to know the different between ker(S) and nullity(S)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The kernel (aka nullspace) of a linear map $T : V \to W$ between vector spaces is always the set $\{x \in V \mid Tx=0_W\}$.  In your case, $S(A) =A + A^T = 0$ means $A^T = -A$.  This describes more than just the zero matrix.

The nullity of $S$ is the dimension (over the base field) of the kernel of $S$.

Comment: So, the ker(S) can be written as [$\begin{matrix} 0&a\\-a&0 \end{matrix}$]?

Comment: @Peter, I have the doubt that if you are asking me... is it so?

Comment: @Peter Yes.  That is the general form of an element in the kernel.

Answer (score 0):

If $A+A^{\top}=0$ it means that the matrix satisfies $A=-A^{\top}$ which is a well known relation for anti-symmetric matrices.

Any $2\times 2$ anti-symmetric matrix is a scalar multiple of 
$\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
0&-1\\1&0
\end{array}
\right]
$, so generates $\ker S$.

The transformation $S$ is not one-to-one because all matrices $\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
0&-a\\a&0
\end{array}
\right]
$ are mapped to the zero  matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Well, by definition
$$\ker(S) = \{A \in F^{2\times2} : S(A) = 0\}$$
and $S(A) = 0$ means that $A+A^t = 0 $, that is, $\ker(S)$ is the set of all anti-symmetric matrices in $F^{2\times2}$.